# Auto-update of exchange rates in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

How can I create a cell in Google Spreadsheet that automatically updates its value when its respective value in the web (i.e. exchange rates) changes?

Is there any function that allows to retrieve the value for exchange rates from the web, so that I don't have to change that each day manually?

Answer (score 5):

To update currency conversion rates on a daily basis, for the Euro to $US for example, do this:

```
=GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:EURUSD";"price")
```

That formula goes in the cell where you want the quote to appear. Instead of "price", you could use "close", if that's what you want for the day prior.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
=GoogleFinance("ticker symbol","price")
```

It will pull USD, GBP, CAD, updating the daily quote.